# WindowManager - drawing on top of the navigation bar (buttons) Android

Tags: java, android, draw, android-windowmanager, android-layoutparams

Good afternoon. I have a service in which the object is created and WindowManager View - is assigned parameter background (mView.setBackgroundColor(color). The fact is that now I have View drawn only over the main desktop screen and status bar, and navigation bar is not affected. How do I do to View draws and on top of the navigation bar (buttons) in the Android? At the moment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mView = new LinearLayout(this);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            0 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);


    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(mView, params);
}
```

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsoyA.jpg)

That is all I have to paint in red, relatively speaking, including a navigation bar. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
int value_below_screen=100;
params.y=-value_below_screen;
```

this will offset the screen below by "value_below_screen"